# Couldn't call method inside method controller in route Nodejs Express Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, routes, nodejs-server

I got two classes; authenticationRoutes.ts and authenticationController.ts. In authenticationRoutes I'm calling 'authenticationController.test', the 'authenticationController.test' method calls 'authenticationController.generateAccessAuthToken' method. Whenever I do this I get the following Error: **Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'generateAccessAuthToken'
of undefined**

```
authenticationRoutes.ts
import { authenticationController } from '../controllers/authenticationController';

        //TEST ROUTE
        this.router.get('/users',  authenticationController.test);
```

```
authenticationController.ts


public test(req: Request, res: Response) {
        dbSequelize().User.findAll({
            where: {
                id: '0'
            },
            attributes: ['id']
        }).then((user: UserInstance[]) => {
            this.generateAccessAuthToken('0').then((response: any) => {
                console.log(response);
                res.send(response);
            });
        })
    }


generateAccessAuthToken(_id: any) {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            await jwt.sign({ id: _id }, SECRET_KEY as string, function (err: Error, token: any) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(token);
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

I want to be able to do what I described without receiving an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will do the trick:

`this.router.get('/users',  authenticationController.test.bind(AuthenticationController));`

Basically, when you have a class `A` with a method `b`, if you pass around `A.b` like:

```
const a = new A();
const b = a.b;
b(); // now 'this' is lost, any reference to `this` in b() code would be undefined
```

You are passing **only the function**. It has nothing to do with the `A` class now, it is **just a function**.

So, among other things, you can use `bind` to explicitly set the `this` context for a function:

```
const a = new A();
const b = a.b.bind(a);
b(); // so now b() is forced to use a as this context
```

I bet there are tons of duplicates about your issue, but I couldn't find anyone fast because the search is tricky (`this` binding in js has A LOT of issues).

Hope this helps.

Comment: when i instantiate the controller class, it says that the class is not a constructor

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and solved it :

```
public test = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        dbSequelize().User.findAll({
            where: {
                id: '0'
            },
            attributes: ['id']
        }).then((user: UserInstance[]) => {
            this.generateAccessAuthToken('0').then((response: any) => {
                console.log(response);
                res.send(response);
            });
        })
    }
```